Scatter Chart Not Updating Correctly for multiple Values at the Same Location
I have two teams, team1 and team2, each containing plot data in the structure mentioned in the link below.
Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-counter-functional-component-forked-3pm6x4
Issue I am facing:

I have created a scatter chart where both team checkboxes are initially checked by default, and everything seems fine.

However, when I uncheck either of the checkboxes, the other plot is also affected and changes its shape. Surprisingly, this only happens with the scatter chart. If I switch to a line chart, everything works, but then I can't show the tooltip at the same location for different values.


Expected Behavior:
When a checkbox is checked or unchecked, the other plot should not be affected and should remain unchanged.
How can I achieve this? Please modify the code and help me with this issue. Alternatively, if there is a way to show tooltips at all locations when the axis has multiple values, I am okay to go with the chart type line instead of scatter.
Thank you.

There's one thing I need to ask you first? Why are you using scatter charts with lineWidth set to 1 which makes it look like a line chart? The simplest way to make it work (without changing the look of the chart) is to simply change the chart type to line and set markers.enabled property to true.

@DominikChudy If I create a line chart and set the markers.enabled property to true, the problem is that when the X-axis has multiple same Y-axis values, the tooltip will only show for one of the values. I want the tooltip to appear at every mark. Is there any other workaround to make it work ?

@DominikChudy Here is the new codesandbox with type set to line and markers.enabled set to true: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-counter-functional-component-forked-tsw9pd. You can see that I can only show the tooltip on one of the markers when multiple markers are at the same X-axis value. I hope this clarifies what I'm trying to explain, Thanks.

Neither with the scatter chart nor the line chart can I see more than one point in the tooltip. However, if you want to show multiple points in the tooltip at once, as they share the same xAxis value, you can set the tooltip.shared property to true. API reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.shared

@DominikChudy Thank you for your reply, I can make that tooltip shared but still the same issue persist -  When they share same axis value it is showing only last one, Also another issue is - making change in checked/unchecked in team name in my shared codesandbox, chart is changing it's shape, Why it is happening. Do you have any inputs on that ?

All right, now I understand what you mean. You have three points with the same x-axis value, for example, and you want to display a tooltip for all of them. For that, we need to stick to the scatter chart, but it won't be a problem. Please take a look at my answer below, where I will explain everything.

It's a known bug in Highcharts library. You can read more about this bug here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18400
The current solution to this problem is to add an id parameter to all your points. Then the lines are not redrawn each time you update the series.
Here's the demo: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-counter-functional-component-forked-y2whfq?file=%2Fsrc%2FCharts.js

Thank you for your help with this. I also posted this question on the Highcharts forum, and they provided another solution. You can check it out here: Highcharts Forum Thread in case you're interested in exploring an alternative approach for the same, Again thanks and marking your answer as accepted.
